# Unable to disable the bootstrap-3 responsiveness

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Presently i am working on bootstrap 3.0 for developing the pages..

I am using the cols-md-* elements for grid view.

While i am trying to disable the responsiveness but it didn't work..

i google it but i didn't found any solution..

I disabled the responsiveness by giving container width to static width (Here my width is 1140px)...

And i go through the Bootstrap link but no luck..

Here is my website (http://lumigren.com/hyd/)..

Answer (score 1):

Use all the instructions for disabling http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive except for adjusting your html to use col-xs.

Then in your CSS move the col-md-* columns styles to outside the 992px min width to around the same location as the col-xs-* OR, probably better, rename all of the col-xs- to col-md- IN your css. Make a back up first. This only works if you were using col-md-* only in your html.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to disable page responsiveness**

1. Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs
2. Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

Hope this may useful.

For Reference use this [LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)